# EF4 Code First & SQLCE 4.0 - Exception when generating DB

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I'm using EF4 4.1 code first and attempting to use SQLCE as the data source.

Everything works perfectly when pointing at a SQL Server 2008 instance, however when I change to SQLCE I get the following exception:

> String column with MaxLength greater than 4000 is not supported.

This is the property it's complaining about, as you can see it's length is set to 1024 characters so I'm stumped as to why it's complaining about 4000?

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Text), RegularExpression("http://www.*"), StringLength(1024)]
[Display(Name = "Page URL (http://www.)")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

This is database initializer from global.asax:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>());
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other string column exceeding 4000 characters length? What will happen if you remove `StringLength` or `DataType` from the property? What will happen if you replace `StringLength` with `MaxLength` from EntityFramework.dll?

Comment: Same problem... I have a feeling the DB isn't generating correctly and the exception being thrown is the result of a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the DataType to NVarchar (from Text)

Comment: String is not a valid EF data annotation? Tried removing the entire DataType item with no luck.